# For any integer $n$, $a_n$ and $b_n$ are two real numbers and function....[CONT]

Tags: limits, continuity

> For any integer $n$, $a_n$ and $b_n$ are two real numbers and function $$f(x)=\begin{cases} a_n + \sin \pi x & x\in [2n, 2n+1] \\\ b_n +\cos \pi x & x\in (2n-1,2n) \end{cases}$$ If $f(x)$ is continuous prove that $a_{n-1} - b_n=-1$

At $x=2n$,

$$f(2n) =a_n$$
And
$$\lim_{x \to 2n^-} b_n+\cos \pi x$$
$$=\lim _{h\to 0^+} b_n +\cos \pi (2n-h)$$
$$=\lim_{h\to 0^+} b_n +\cos \pi h$$
$$=b_n+1$$
So $$a_n-b_n=1$$

But I am not able to get $a_{n-1}$ in any expression. How should I do that?

Edit [image]

For the part I am not clear:

Why has the RHL been chosen as the second function at $x=2n+1$ and why does $b_n$ change to $b_{n+1}$?

Comment: I upvoted; nice work shown, nicely presented.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally, I would criticize if someone *answered* without explaining to the OP where he went wrong.  In this case however, the OP should be able to reverse engineer his mistake by using my answer.

At $x = (2n-1), \;f(x) = a_{(n-1)} + \sin \,\pi(2n-1) = a_{(n-1)}.$

As $x$ approaches $(2n-1)$ **from above**, 
$f(x)$ approaches $b_n + \cos(2n-1)\pi = b_n - 1.$

Since $f(x)$ is continuous at $x = (2n-1), \;b_n - 1 = a_{(n-1)}.$

**Addendum**: Response to Aditya's questions

(1) 
When $x$ exactly equals $(2n+1), \;f(x) = a_n + \sin \,\pi(2n+1).$ 
Therefore, when $x$ exactly equals $(2[n-1] + 1),$ 
$f(x) = a_{[n-1]} \sin \,\pi(2[n-1]+1).$

(2) 
When $x \,\in \,(2n-1,2n) \;f(x) = b_n + \cos \,\pi(x).$ 
Note that when $x$ is approaching $(2n-1)$ from above, 
$x \,\in \,(2n-1,2n).$

This means that as $x$ is approaching $(2n-1)$ from above, 
$f(x)$ is approaching $b_n + \cos \,\pi (2n-1).$ 
Note that $\cos \,\pi (2n-1) \;=\; \cos \,(-\pi) = -1.$

.....

Please respond if I still have not answered your questions.

**Addendum-2**: Response to Aditya's added questions

First of all, please see if you have a specific question about my original analysis (at the start of this *answer*),
as opposed to analysis that you originated or analysis that you got from
someone else.  If my analysis seems clear and valid to you, then my analysis
represents a solution.  That being said, I am happy to attack your questions.

(1) 
Why has the the RHL been chosen as the second function at $x = (2n + 1)$?

Go back to the basic definition: 
when $x \,\in (2n-1, 2n), \;f(x) = b_n + cos \pi(x).$

This means that when $x \,\in (2[n+1] - 1, 2[n+1]), \;f(x) = b_{[n+1]} + cos \pi(x).$ 
Note that $x = (2n+1) \Rightarrow x = (2[n+1] - 1).$

It looks like there is a **typo** in the statement that you are questioning.
Suppose that $0 < h < 1.$ 
Then $2n + 1 + h$ **will be** in $(2n + 1, 2n + 2),$ while 
$2n + 1 - h$ **will instead be** in $(2n, 2n + 1),$

This means that in order to make sense of the line that you are questioning,
you have to assume that $2n + 1 + h$ was intended.

(2) 
Why does $b_n$ change to $b_{(n+1)}.$

I repeat the pertinent part of what I said in (1):

Go back to the basic definition: 
when $x \,\in (2n-1, 2n), \;f(x) = b_n + cos \pi(x).$

This means that when $x \,\in (2[n+1] - 1, 2[n+1]), \;f(x) = b_{[n+1]} + cos \pi(x).$

.....

Again, please respond if I still have not answered your questions.  **Also,** I am particularly interested in your reaction to the analysis I gave at the start of my *answer.*

Comment: Why would $a_n$ turn to $a_{n-1}$ if $x=2n-1$. Also the main problem I have is why do we pick $b_n+\cos...$ if $x\to 2n-1^+$?

Comment: @Aditya Please see the addendum that I added to my answer.

Comment: Please check my edited question to see where I am having the problem

Comment: @Aditya I added a 2nd addendum to my answer to attack your added questions.

Comment: Wouldn’t the second function be the LHD if it’s domain’s right extreme is $2n+1$?

Comment: As for your initial analysis, I have no qualms with that

Comment: @Aditya "Wouldn’t the second function be the LHD if it’s domain’s right extreme is (2n+1)?"  **Yes** it would, which is why I presumed the **typo.**  Also, I emphasize that even without the typo, the presentation is convoluted.  If you regard the (concise) analysis at the start of my *answer* as clear and valid, then I see no reason that the problem's solution involve *convolutions.*

Answer (score 0):

Hint:  You found the condition for $x$ even.  What about $x$ odd?  Notice that $2n-1 = 2(n-1)+1$, so you will be comparing the second piece in the definition of $f$ at $n$ with the first piece at $n-1$.

Comment: I don’t understand

Comment: @Aditya : When you write $x = 2n$, is $x$ odd?

Comment: I get that, I don’t understand what functions you want me to use calculate the limits.

Comment: @Aditya : Suppose $x = 5$.  Which pieces of $f$ and which values of $n$ do you use in those pieces for the limits?

Comment: @Aditya : When $x = 5$, you will find a relation between $a_2$ and $b_3$.  That is, odd $x$s give the relation you are missing.